# Getting joda.time: NoClassDefFoundError error even excluding this from pom. when trying to upload image on S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to upload image file on S3 bucket using transfer manager in Java. I added the following dependency in my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.0.002</version>
</dependency>
```

and try excluding joda time dependency.

Still i am getting error like: "**ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone","messageDetail":"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErro**

Please help also share if i am using wrong way to upload image.

Comment: You are missing joda time jar in your Lambda package jar. Make sure jar has proper jar packaged. You need to pack all dependencies with your Lambda function.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html and https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/444

Comment: Why are you using a library from 7 years ago?

Comment: I have also tried it with Following
                       <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.132</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
     <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
Still getting same error,
Can you please tell what i am doing wrong?
I have referenced the code from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, Issue is resolved now.
I just added Joda time dependency instead exlusing it in pom.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<!-- https://mvnbuild.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

It has the class you're missing: https://mvnbuild.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9